# Python faster than rust with py03

Tags: python, performance, rust

I am trying to speed up some python code using rust bindings with py03.

i have implemented the following function in both python and rust:

```py
def _play_action(state, action):

    temp = state.copy()
    i1, j1, i2, j2 = action
    h1 = abs(temp[i1][j1])
    h2 = abs(temp[i2][j2])
    if temp[i1][j1] < 0:
        temp[i2][j2] = -(h1 + h2)
    else:
        temp[i2][j2] = h1 + h2
    temp[i1][j1] = 0
    return temp
```

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn play_action(state: [[i32; 9]; 9], action : [usize;4]) -> [[i32; 9]; 9] {
    let mut s = state.clone();

    let h1 = s[action[0]][action[1]];
    let h2 = s[action[2]][action[3]];

    s[action[0]][action[1]] = 0;
    s[action[2]][action[3]] = h1.signum() * (h1 + h2).abs();

    s
```

And to my great surprise the python version is faster... Any idea why?

Comment: Did you compile with --release and can you avoid `let mut s = state.clone();` by using `mut state` parameter ?

Comment: This code isn't doing much which costs time. The overhead of calling a rust function from python might be too high compared to what the function actually does.

Comment: @OussamaGammoudi just did thx, did non make it much faster sadly.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich this code is part of a much bigger program aka taking in a batch of 64 9x9 boards, find the actions (~200 per board), applying all of them and returning the modified boards. This function is just symptomatic of what i am trying to show.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by the overhead of the communication between python and Rust, the data you're passing is too small so I assume you're calling `play_action` many times. a better approach would be to batch your calls

```
#[pyfunction]
fn play_actions(data: Vec<([[i32; 9]; 9],[usize;4])>) -> Vec<[[i32; 9]; 9]> {
   data.into_iter()
      .map(|(state,action)| play_action(state,action))
      .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}

fn play_action(state: [[i32; 9]; 9], action : [usize;4]) -> [[i32; 9]; 9] {
    let mut s = state.clone();

    let h1 = s[action[0]][action[1]];
    let h2 = s[action[2]][action[3]];

    s[action[0]][action[1]] = 0;
    s[action[2]][action[3]] = h1.signum() * (h1 + h2).abs();

    s
}
```

Comment: Working with Python objects as well (for the `state` at least) since only two locations get touched.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the function written in rust from Python, there will have to be a conversion from Python objects to rust data structures. The time that this takes is overhead.

Since your function seems pretty small, it could easily be that the overhead overwhelms the runtime of the function.

I would encourage you to *profile* your python code (using the `cProfile` module) before trying to make it faster. Profiling and the insight in the behavior of your code that it provides can enable significant performance gains.
[Here](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/programming/profiling-python-scripts-1-stl2pov.html) is a link to the first of a series of articles that I've written about python profiling.

If you do a lot of number crunching, see if your problem is a good fit for `numpy`.

If a relatively small function takes up a lot of the execution time because it is called very often, try using the `functools.cache` decorator.

Keep in mind that a better algorithm generally beats optimizations.

Comment: Thanks i didnt know about cProfile, it is such a great tool! The issue is that i cant get cprofile to give the times in micro seconds as my code is mostly little funcions called many times my profile is full of 0.000 s

Comment: When using `cProfile`  with a program that has lots of little functions that are called otfen, use  the `-s cumtime` option. That will sort by the sum of all calls for a function or expression. It is normal that the **percall** columns are often 0.000.